# Function To Generate new mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to create a function using Meteor.js that will generate a new mongodb collection everytime it is run. I'm wondering how and if this can be done.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to accomplish? i.e. Why do you want dynamic collections in the first place?

Comment: I'm trying to make a collection for each user to store their information

Comment: Use the [accounts](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api) api for that instead. I have yet to encounter a situation where dynamic collection creation made sense.

Comment: I agree with @DavidWeldon: Unless the documents in each collection differ _a lot_, it is usually better to keep them in one collection and attach a field denoting the owning user instead. Makes it much more scalable (there _is_ a limit on how many collections a database can hold), analyzable (you only have to run one aggregation instead of multiple) and maintainable (try to dynamically shard collections...).